# Is requires(std::derived_from<...>) equivalent to static_assert(std::is_base_of<...>)?

Tags: c++, c++20, static-assert, requires-clause

I'm attempting to learn requires expressions as a stepping stone towards getting comfortable with the concepts mechanic. The easiest way I could come up with was to ease into it by replacing all my `static_assert` expressions in any templates with `requires` expressions.

One that is a little tricky to understand is the difference between `std::is_base_of_v<>` and `std::derived_from<>`.

Are the following `requires` and `static_assert` expressions equivalent, i.e., do the same thing? If not, what will? My intent was to require, after any possible reference/cv/pointer decoration was removed, that `GameType` and `GameBase` were derived from each other:

```cpp
class GameBase {
//...
};

//...

#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename GameType>
requires(std::derived_from<GameType, GameBase>)
class Engine {
public:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::remove_cvref_t<std::remove_pointer_t<GameBase>>, std::remove_cvref_t<std::remove_pointer_t<GameType>>>, "GameType template parameter is not derived from GameBase.");
    static void Initialize(const std::string& title, const std::string& cmdString) noexcept;
    static void Run() noexcept;
    static void Shutdown() noexcept;
    static const bool Available() noexcept;

private:
    static inline bool m_initCalled{false};
    static inline bool m_shutdownCalled{false};
};
```

Comment: std::derived_from == true only for public inheritance or exact same class. std::is_base_of == true also for private inheritance. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095310/c-concepts-vs-static-assert

Comment: @康桓瑋 I'm confused how that answer predates c++20 by 6 years. Anyhow, I think it's a great dupe except there's a few tidbits that isn't quite accurate (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example that answer your question.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct foo;

template <typename T>
requires(std::same_as<T, int>)
struct foo<T>{};

template <typename T>
requires(std::same_as<T, double>)
struct foo<T>{};

template <typename T>
struct bar;

/// error, static_assert cannot be used as specilization
/*
template <typename T>
struct bar<T>{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, T>);
};

template <typename T>
struct bar<T>{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, T>);
};
*/
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Essentially posting code by itself as an answer isn't really helpful.

Comment: It is a situation that you can use requires (foo) but cannot use static_assert (bar). @Casey

Comment: Explanations belong in the answer. As stated, the answer is basically code-only, which typically is not helpful. Use words to explain, and use the example to augment (not replace) that explanation.

Comment: the comment "/// error, static_assert cannot be used as specilization" is the all explanation your need, what else do you want? @JaMiT

Comment: @macomphy I suppose one way to describe what I want is something that someone other than yourself would find easy to understand. You can argue until you're blue in the face that you've done all that is required of you, but that won't help others figure out what you're trying to communicate.

Comment: I have only one question. Have you tried to compile this example on some place before you say it's not clear? @JaMiT

Comment: @macomphy *"Have you tried to compile this example on some place before you say it's not clear?"* -- No. And I see no reason to. In fact, I would recommend **against** compiling code found on the internet before the purpose of the code is clear.

Comment: Don't you even know of an online compiler site? @JaMiT

Comment: @macomphy You said only one question. I entertained that one, despite its questionable relevance. Have fun arguing until you are blue in the face.